# Iwahori versus Bruhat decompositions

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, proof-verification

I am faced with the following issue that I do not understand but seems contradictory, coming from the book of Roberts and Schmidt about $GSp(4)$. Consider a local non-archimedean field $F$, let $p$ be its maximal ideal, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers and $G=GSp(4, F)$. We are interested in the following Klingen congruence subgroup
$$K = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
p & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
p & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
p & p & p & \mathcal{O}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

(from now on all the subgroups written in this matrix-entries form is meant to be their intersection with $GSp(4, F)$. I am interested in computing the index of this subgroup in the maximal compact subgroup $K_0$ (where all the entries are integers).

**Iwahori decomposition**
We have
$$
K = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &  & &  \\
p & 1 & &  \\
p &  & 1 &  \\
p & p & p & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathcal{O}^\times & &  &  \\
 & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} &  \\
 & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} &  \\
 &  &  & \mathcal{O}^\times
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
 & 1 &  & \mathcal{O} \\
 &  & 1 & \mathcal{O} \\
 &  &  & 1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

so that in particular by decomposing the left subgroup we should obtain
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\bigsqcup_{a, b, c \in \mathcal{O}/p} 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &  &  &  \\
a & 1  & &  \\
b & & 1 & \\
c & b & -a & 1
\end{array}
\right)
K
$$

(where the fact that the entries on the right are this way comes from the conditions of belonging to $GSp(4)$). So that in particular the index should be, writting $N(p)$ for the norm of $p$,

> $$[K_0:K] =N(p)^3$$

**Bruhat decomposition**
On the other hand, introducing the subgroup
$$
Q = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
 & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
 & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O} \\
 & & & \mathcal{O}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

the Bruhat decomposition yields that for any field $k$,
$$
GSp(4, k) = Q 
\sqcup Qx 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & k &  & \\
 & 1 &  & \\
 & & 1 & k \\
 & & & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\sqcup 
Qxy 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & & k  &  \\
 & 1 & k & k \\
 & & 1 &  \\
 & & & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\sqcup 
Qxyx
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & k & k & k\\
 & 1 &  & k\\
 & & 1 & k \\
 & & & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

where the transformations $x$ and $y$ are defined by
$$x= 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 & 1&  & \\
1 &  &  & \\
 & &  & 1 \\
 & &1 & 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$y =
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &  &  &\\
 &  & 1 & \\
 & -1 & &  \\
 & & & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In particular if $k$ is the finite field with $N(p)$ elements, the index we search for is exactly the cardinality of $GSp(4,k) / Q$, and this one is $(1+N(p))(1+N(p)^2)$, so that we should say

> $$[K_0:K] =(1+N(p))(1+N(p)^2)$$

Here is the question following from this discussion:

> Both results are different, what is
>   happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Iwahori-decomposition computation is a bit too free with quotient computations.  It would work fine for vector spaces, which is, in some sense, why you get the correct leading term in your count; but there are additional subtleties on the group level that it does not take into account—among other things, that some of the entries denoted by $\mathcal O$ can be $0$, but some cannot!

The same computation would suggest that the quotient of $\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$ by its Borel subgroup of upper-triangular matrices should have as coset representatives the lower uni-triangular matrices $u_-(c) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ c & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, whereas actually there is another coset, the one containing $w_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Actually a better way to think about it is that most coset representatives are of the form $u_+(c)w_0$, where $u_+(c)$ is the transpose of $u_-(c)$, and only the trivial coset is not of this form; it just happens that $u_+(c)w_0$ and $u_-(c^{-1})$ lie in the same coset when $c \ne 0$.

Your count *via* the Bruhat decomposition shows what’s going on here:  you get $(1 + N(p))(1 + N(p)^2) = 1 + N(p) + N(p)^2 + N(p)^3$, which suggests, correctly, that we have stratified $\mathbb P^3k$ by affine spaces of the obvious dimensions, corresponding to the Weyl-group elements $1$, $x$, $x y$, and $x y x$ (which are minimal-length representatives in the quotient by an appropriate parabolic subgroup, which is doubtless what led you to choose them!).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to understand a bit more your sentence "we have stratified $\mathbb P^3k$ by affine spaces of the obvious dimensions, corresponding to the Weyl-group elements $1$, $x$, $x y$, and $x y x$ (which are minimal-length representatives in the quotient by an appropriate parabolic subgroup)". I think my understanding of the Bruhat decomposition and these matters of decompositions lacks something hidden in such details/intuition

Comment: I mean it very literally:  that, for example, the parameterisation of $Q\backslash Q x Q$ that you suggest puts it in bijection with $\mathbb A^2k$, and this may be viewed as geometric (not just an accident of finite point counts) in the sense that it is compatible with unramified base change.  Can you tell me more about what you’d like to know?